# move TD to new TR

Tags: table

I am trying to create this output in Salesforce:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Im using apex:pageBlockSection to display the content and when SF renders I get this: 
`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Is there an apex function that would tell SF to separate the last TR into 2 new ones?

Comment: Can you post your Visualforce?

Comment: pageBlockSection always render as a one or two columns table, define with the columns parameter. If you want to have the last TR into 2 new ones, you need to add an empty outputText or maybe a pageBlockSectionItem with a &nbsp;

Comment: In order to span two columns into the one (the second and third TR's in your first example) you need to add a `colspan` parameter to the TD tag: `<td colspan="2">test</td>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create a layout like you want you can use a nested `pageBlockSection` element. The first "wrapper" section has only one column and the nested section  - two. A simple combibation of those two sections results like this:

[image]

Here is the code. Note that the CSS is used only to remove the unnecessary paddings so the columns looks like the same:

```
<style>
.myBlock .dataCol {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

</style>

<div class="myBlock">
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >       
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>Item 1</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>Item 2</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>        
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>Item3</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>Item4</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</div>
```